Macbook Air - Mail app crashes following Migration from older MacBook Air
Migrated from Macbook Air running Mojave, Mail version 12.4. to Macbook Air running Sequoia, Mail version 16.0. Opening mail pops up a window with the message "updating mail database" - this disappears, app doesn't open.

As a first step, please go to System Settings > Internet Accounts and disable all your mail accounts. Try again to launch Mail. If it launches successfully, re-enable the accounts one at a time and see what happens.

Did that, no change. Should I try actually removing them as opposed to disabling?

There are three basic types of mail account: IMAP, POP, and Exchange. Do you know which types you have?

Thanks for your responses - I've now fixed it by editing the PersistenceInfo.plist file in the Mail Library (found on a thread in Apple Discussions).

It would be helpful to others if you wrote up your solution as an answer and accepted it.

It won't let me post the whole method - but you can find it here:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255381553
Close Mail.
Open Finder and navigate to ~/Library/Mail.
Locate the V10 folder and move it to your desktop.
Open the PersistenceInfo.plist file in TextEdit.
Change all occurrences of V10 (or any other V-number) to V2.
Save the file and close TextEdit.
Relaunch Mail.
Mail will rebuild the database.
It worked!
